# alert box not coming up - what is incorrect in this function?

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function check_phone(){
    var x=$('#phone1').val();
    var landline = /^([0-9]{4}[\-]{1}[0-9]{7})$/;
    var mobile = /^(?:\([2-9]\d{2}\)\ ?|[2-9]\d{2}(?:\-?|\ ?))[2-9]\d{2}[- ]?\d{4}$/;
    if (landline.test(x))
alert('first condition');
        $('#phone1').css('border','2px solid #00a500');
    else if(mobile.test(x))
alert('second condition');
        $('#phone1').css('border','2px solid #00a500');
    else
        $('#phone1').css('border','2px solid #a50000');
alert('third condition');
}
</script>

<input type="text" value="" name="phone1" id="phone1" onchange="check_phone()" required />
```

When I press tab after entering a phone number, it does not show the alert boxes from check_phone() function. Is it even entering the function and checking it? It does not even style the textbox as per the css mentioned in the function. How can I find out? Please help

Comment: give id.. you just gave name..

Comment: I was not knowing this. thank you for the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the if block do not have the ending brackets `)` and put them in the curly brackets

```
if (landline.test(x))
{
alert('first condition');
        $('#phone1').css('border','2px solid #00a500');
}
    else if(mobile.test(x))
{
alert('second condition');
        $('#phone1').css('border','2px solid #00a500');
}
    else
{
        $('#phone1').css('border','2px solid #a50000');
alert('third condition');
}
```

Also change

```
<input type="text" value="" name="phone1" id="phone1" onchange="check_phone()" required />
```

Comment: Thanks buddy... can the value of the textbox be replaced immediately after losing focus by just concatenating country code? eg if someone enters 9999999999 and press tab, it should show +919999999999

Comment: @user3736026:- Yes it can be done. However I would suggest you to ask a new question for that so as to get more attention. Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks. I wish to try this out first before asking a new question. I thought it may be just a one liner code.

Comment: There is a small problem in the code. When I enter a correct mobile number it shows me two alerts (second condition) and (third condition) whereas it should show only second. Why is this happenning?

Comment: @user3736026:- The else part also need to be in the `{}`. My bad. Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

give **id**.. you just gave **name**.

```
<input type="text" value="" name="phone1" id="phone1" onchange="check_phone()" required />
```

Also add braces for `if()`

```
 if (landline.test(x) {
alert('first condition');
        $('#phone1').css('border','2px solid #00a500');
}
    else if(mobile.test(x) {
alert('second condition');
        $('#phone1').css('border','2px solid #00a500');
}
    else{
        $('#phone1').css('border','2px solid #a50000');
alert('third condition');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the closing bracket `(` of each condition `if (landline.test(x)` and without `{}` it will only execute alert line and not the css styling won't be a part of that condition so you should use:

```
if (landline.test(x)) {
    alert('first condition');
    $('#phone1').css('border','2px solid #00a500');
}
```

for all conditions.

and also change the following line as well, as the @arunrc pointed out, you need to give the `id` attribute to access it from code like that.

```
<input type="text" value="" name="phone1" id="phone1" onchange="check_phone()" required />
```

Comment: There is a small problem in the code. When I enter a correct mobile number it shows me two alerts (second condition) and (third condition) whereas it should show only second. Why is this happenning?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a lot of closing parentheses and brackets. [Here a `working` example](http://jsfiddle.net/oyzy4x7r/) on jsfiddle.